# Create-react-app reload on service worker update

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, create-react-app

I want to modify `create-react-app` service worker [file](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/d57fd37d2d9df1d40aed061e4446831be70446ca/packages/react-scripts/template/src/serviceWorker.js) and implement popup message which will ask user to update app if newer service worker is ready to be activated. I'm almost done with the solution but have one pitfall. I want to reload the app when user confirms service worker update popup, so I've added some coded to the end of `register` function, see below:

```
export default function register(config) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" && "serviceWorker" in navigator) {
    // The URL constructor is available in all browsers that support SW.
    const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location)
    if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
      // Our service worker won't work if PUBLIC_URL is on a different origin
      // from what our page is served on. This might happen if a CDN is used to
      // serve assets; see https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2374
      return
    }

    window.addEventListener("load", () => {
      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`

      if (isLocalhost) {
        // This is running on localhost. Lets check if a service worker still exists or not.
        checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config)

        // Add some additional logging to localhost, pointing developers to the
        // service worker/PWA documentation.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
          console.log(
            "This web app is being served cache-first by a service " +
              "worker."
          )
        })
      } else {
        // Is not local host. Just register service worker
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config)
      }

      let preventDevToolsReloadLoop
      navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener("controllerchange", function() {
        // ensure refresh is called only once
        if (preventDevToolsReloadLoop) {
          return
        }

        preventDevToolsReloadLoop = true
        console.log("reload")
        window.location.reload(true)
      })
    })
  }
}
```

But the problem is that it reloads the app also on first visit, when there doesn't exist any service worker yet. How can I solve it?

Comment: How about set preventDevToolsReloadLoop to true in the local state instead. And unset it at the top after `export default function register(config) {`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Update to `react-scripts` ^3.2.0.  Verify that you have the new version of serviceWorker.ts or .js.  The old one was called `registerServiceWorker.ts` and the register function did not accept a configuration object.  Note that this solution only works well if you are Not lazy-loading.

then in index.tsx:

```
  serviceWorker.register({
    onUpdate: registration => {
      alert('New version available!  Ready to update?');
      if (registration && registration.waiting) {
        registration.waiting.postMessage({ type: 'SKIP_WAITING' });
      }
      window.location.reload();
    }
  });
```

The latest version of the ServiceWorker.ts `register()`function accepts a config object with a callback function where we can handle upgrading.  If we post a message `SKIP_WAITING` this tells the service worker to stop waiting and to go ahead and load the new content after the next refresh.  In this example I am using a javascript alert to inform the user.  Please replace this with a custom toast.

The reason this `postMessage` function works is because under the hood CRA is using `workbox-webpack-plugin` which includes a `SKIP_WAITING` listener.

**More About Service Workers**

good guide: https://redfin.engineering/how-to-fix-the-refresh-button-when-using-service-workers-a8e27af6df68

CRA issue discussing service worker cache:  https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5316

If you are not using CRA, you can use workbox directly: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox

Comment: I already solved it, but forgot to post the solution, thanks! :-)

Comment: Very clean solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Completing [@jfbloom22's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60263791/2928168):

As you probably want to ask the user after an update has been detected with something more complex than a plain `alert`, you need to ensure the `registration` object is available from inside the React's components tree and save it to use after the user accepts to update (for example, by clicking a button).

As an option, in a component you can create a custom event listener on a global object like `document` and fire this event when the `onUpdate` callback passed to `serviceWorker.register()`, passing to it the `resgistration` object as extra data.

This is exactly what my recently published [Service Worker Updater](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@3m1/service-worker-updater) does (some self-promotion). To use it you just need to:

- Add it to the dependencies:

```
yarn add @3m1/service-worker-updater
```

- Use it in your `index.js`:

```js
import { onServiceWorkerUpdate } from '@3m1/service-worker-updater';

// ...

// There are some naming changes in newer Create React App versions
serviceWorkerRegistration.register({
  onUpdate: onServiceWorkerUpdate
});
```

- Use it in some of your React components:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withServiceWorkerUpdater } from '@3m1/service-worker-updater';

const Updater = (props) => {
  const {newServiceWorkerDetected, onLoadNewServiceWorkerAccept} = props;
  return newServiceWorkerDetected ? (
    <>
      New version detected.
      <button onClick={ onLoadNewServiceWorkerAccept }>Update!</button>
    </>
  ) : null; // If no update is available, render nothing
}

export default withServiceWorkerUpdater(Updater);
```

Comment: I really want to say THANKS for this great module, I implemented it and it works flawlessly !

Comment: Brilliant piece of work. One issue with it though, is if you refresh a tab before updating you don't get another notification.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add reload funtion in **installingWorker.state === 'installed'**

```
     if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
        if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
          // do something ..
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer was getting a blank white screen after the reload, for me.

Adding the `await registration.unregister();` solved it.

```
serviceWorker.register({
  onUpdate: async registration => {
    // We want to run this code only if we detect a new service worker is
    // waiting to be activated.
    // Details about it: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle
    if (registration && registration.waiting) {
      await registration.unregister();
      // Makes Workbox call skipWaiting()
      registration.waiting.postMessage({ type: 'SKIP_WAITING' });
      // Once the service worker is unregistered, we can reload the page to let
      // the browser download a fresh copy of our app (invalidating the cache)
      window.location.reload();
    }
  },
});
```

from https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5316#issuecomment-591075209

Answer (score 0):

The [answer from @jfbloom22](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60263791/110560) worked for me as well, except that I wasn't seeing updates show up proactively. It was working when I'd open a new browser and go to the app, but if a browser was already open and updates were published nothing was happening. (For those who are using **Redux** or something similar, my solution to showing something better than an `alert` was to `dispatch` an update to a Boolean variable, to which my React component tree could respond. Same concept as some other solutions mentioned here.)

For **proactive updates**, I updated my `serviceWorkerRegistration.ts` module like so:

```
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then((registration) => {

      setInterval(() => {      //ADDED
        registration.update(); //ADDED
      }, 1000 * 60 * 10);      //ADDED

      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        // ...
```

Checking every 10 minutes was good enough for me, but you could update the `setInterval` to wait as long or short as you'd like.

(With thanks to [an article on Medium](https://medium.com/toplyne-engineering/pwa-update-notifications-in-a-react-application-f5680d51bb2), which I combined with the answer here, to get a full solution.)