# React App with Service worker - Force update cache

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker, browser-cache

I am trying different approaches to clearing the browser cache on application update.
This has proven to be more difficult than expected. :)

My refresh on new version code looks like this.

My app mounts in `app.js`

I have this code in `serviceWorker-base.js` (I am using workbox)

```
addEventListener('message', function(messageEvent){
  if (messageEvent.data === 'skipWaiting') return skipWaiting();
});
```

My `app.js`

```
// skipWaiting() functions
function promptUserToRefresh(registration) {
  // this is just an example - don't use window.confirm in real life; it's terrible
  if (window.confirm("New version available! Refresh?")) {
    registration.waiting.postMessage('skipWaiting')
  }
}
function listenForWaitingServiceWorker(registration) {
  console.log('listenForWaitingServiceWorker', registration)
  function awaitStateChange() {
    registration.installing.addEventListener('statechange', function() {
      if (this.state === 'installed') promptUserToRefresh(registration)
    })
  }
  if (!registration) return
  if (registration.waiting) return promptUserToRefresh(registration)
  if (registration.installing) awaitStateChange()
  registration.addEventListener('updatefound', awaitStateChange)
}
//**

const enableServiceWorker = true
const serviceWorkerAvailable = ('serviceWorker' in navigator) ? true : false
// Register service worker
if (enableServiceWorker && serviceWorkerAvailable) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/serviceWorker.js')
  .then( (registration) => {
    console.log('Service worker registered', registration)
    listenForWaitingServiceWorker(registration) // ** skipWaiting() code
  })
}

// Install prompt event handler
export let deferredPrompt
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (event) => {
  // Prevent Chrome 76 and later from showing the mini-infobar
  event.preventDefault()
  deferredPrompt = event // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
  try{
    showInstallPromotion()
  }catch(e){
    console.error('showInstallPromotion()', e)
  }
})
window.addEventListener('appinstalled', (event) => {
  console.log('a2hs installed')
})
```

My question is - Would it be possible to add a function to clear the browser cache when the user clicks "OK"?

Something along the lines of:

```
const refreshCacheAndReload = () => {
  if (caches) {
    // Service worker cache should be cleared with caches.delete()
    caches.keys().then((names) => {
      for (const name of names) {
        caches.delete(name);
      }
    });
  }
  // delete browser cache and hard reload
  window.location.reload(true);
};
```

Or are there better ways to force the browser to clear the cache?

Kind regards/K

**UPDATE**
The reason for wanting to clear the cache is to force the client to receive a new version of the application when a new release is deployed. (bundle files, css-files, etc.) As of today this requires hard reload and/or several reloads. Sometimes the application only receives parts of the new application on first reload.

Comment: Before I answer the question as asked, could you clarify _why_ you'd want to clear the cache? If you're using `workbox-precaching`, then explicitly clearing the cache is a bad idea, as `workbox-precaching` itself manages the cache. If you're using `workbox-strategies` + `workbox-routing`, then using the `ExpirationPlugin` may be a better alternative to clearing things.

Comment: Hi Jeff! Thanks for your reply! I am not using workbox-precacing, only workbox-strategies and workbox-routing. What I wish to accomplish is for the user to get a new version of the application when a new release is deployed. As of today this requires hard reload and/or several reloads. I have clarified the original question. Kind regards /K

Comment: It's possible to use a function that the one you included in your question to clear the cache programmatically, yes.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to add code to delete cache in function "promptUserToRefresh()". Kind regards /K

Comment: Hi Jeff! The method works! But I am now using  workbox-precaching + workbox-strategies + workbox-routing and would like to use the ExpirationPlugin for clearing the cache. Could you point me in the right direction as how to implement this? See separate question here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65276766/clear-cache-using-workbox-expiration-in-workbox-6-0-2 Many thanks! /K

Comment: You may want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55245427/create-react-app-reload-on-service-worker-update/67013187#67013187